# Export Lyx to Latex from CLI, output only to stdout

Tags: lyx

Is there a way to export from Lyx to Latex using the CLI so that in only writes to stdout, and not to a file?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not currently possible. You can make a feature request [here](http://www.lyx.org/trac). It might make sense to implement it for the -E option. So you could do something like `lyx -E latex - yourfile.lyx`, where `-` means output to STDOUT. I think that's consistent with what some Unix commands do (e.g. `wget`).

So in the meantime, you will have to output to a file and then `cat` that file to command you want to pipe to.

Note that the OP posted an enhancement that can be followed [here](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9919).